# I'm learning CSS, How can i style a submit button using external css. I am trying something like this but i have no idea how to do this

Tags: html, css

how can i style a submit button using a external css file
it is the code

```
<div class="bu">
<form action="#">
<button type="submit" class="but" value="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: no different than an inline stylesheet. Have you styled a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.but {
  background: lightBlue;
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="bu">
    <form action="#">
        <button type="submit" class="but" value="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There are three ways we can use css to style your component

1. Inline
2. Internal
3. External

These the ways are clearly explained in https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Since you are learning css , this also will hlep to you.
https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-create-a-css-external-style-sheet/

If you need an external style sheet,

1. Create a style.css file
2. Link that using `style` tag inside your html component `head` tag

Answer (score 0):

firstly import the file at the top of the html file, like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">`. REPLACE `mystyle.css` with your file. After that in the css file, add ```.but`{}``, and finally add the style in the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting started it will be much simpler to include the styles in the HTML. This is how you can embed CSS styles in HTML

```html
<style>
 button {
  color: read;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
 }
</style>

<div class="bu">
<form action="#">
<button type="submit" class="but" value="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
</div>
```